# Spring integration jdbc message store performance

Tags: performance, jdbc, store, spring-integration, aggregator

I was using the SimpleMessageStore ( memory ) as the default Store for an Aggregator, but as i need
persistent store, i started using a jdbc solution backed up by Mysql 5.5

But i'm really concerned about its performance, as using a PerfTest ( databene's contiperf ), memory store achieved up to 6000 messages/sec, whereas using mysql ( or redis, or mongo ), i can't achieve more than 15-20 messages/sec.

```
   <int:aggregator      id="XDRAggegator"
                        input-channel="mqChannel"
                        output-channel="publishChannel"
                        message-store="jdbc-messageStore"
   ....

    <bean id="reaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
        <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="jdbc-messageStore"/>
        <property name="timeout"           value="${msg.timeout}"/>
   </bean>

<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">    
    <task:scheduled ref="reaper" method="run" fixed-rate="${reaper.rate}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>


<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>

  <int-jdbc:message-store id="jdbc-messageStore" data-source="dataSource"  />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" >
       <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.host}:3306/XDR?autoReconnect=true&amp;cachePrepStmts=true&amp;prepStmtCacheSize=50" />
       <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
       <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
       <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="1"/>
       <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="2"/>    
       <property name="connectionTimeoutInMs"   value="1000" />             
       <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
       <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="4"/>
       <property name="partitionCount" value="4"/>
       <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2"/>                              
       <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="10"/>
       <property name="closeConnectionWatch" value="false"/>
 </bean>
```

Am i missing something ? 
I'm using default schema that comes into spring-integration-jdbc library.

Comment: What version of Spring Integration?

Comment: Sorry, did not see the comment !, 2.2.3, latest.

Comment: You find solution for this problem?